# What is the current status of the snark theorem?

Tags: graph-theory, open-problem

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snark_(graph_theory)) writes "W. T. Tutte conjectured that every snark has the Petersen graph as a minor... In 1999, Neil Robertson, Daniel P. Sanders, Paul Seymour, and Robin Thomas announced a proof of this conjecture.[16] As of 2012, their proof remains largely unpublished.[17]"

These authors have an [arxiv paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.4352.pdf) (submitted 2014, updated November 2015, although the PDF weirldy claims it was updated in September 2018, three years after its publication). This arxiv paper cites no less than three unpublished papers [5,6,8] and which does not appear to have been published itself.

It has been twenty years! (Even twenty-five in the case of citation [6]...). Why is Wikipedia this even listing as a theorem? Is there a general acceptance that this has indeed been proved, and if so, why is none of this getting published?

Comment: It seems that the conjecture is not yet proven, so in fact, it should be listed as a conjecture. An announced proof is not necessarily a proof.

Comment: This is an interesting question; Doug West's book (Intro to Graph Theory) corroborates your fact, saying it has been proved in a series of papers starting in 2001. I'm interested to know some more of this history -- following.

Comment: As no other reactions seem to be forthcoming, I guess Peter's comment should count as the answer. Peter, if you like to earn points, please put it in as an answer.

Comment: Something to note: the "2018" date in the arxiv version will probably be to do with the PDF being rebuilt from the TeX source (arxiv doesn't store PDFs forever, but builds them as required), and the authors having used \date{\today} so that the date is set to equal the last time it was compiled...